# Is it possible to fill all of your inventory's slots?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

I have:

> five bottles, every one of Ravio's items, the net, the lantern, the hint glasses, a scoot fruit, and a foul fruit.

There's one slot left. Am I missing something, or is it just impossible to fill this slot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't gotten there yet myself, but according to the Internet:

> you get the last item in the final boss battle.

Answer (score 4):

> You get the light bow in the last boss fight.

Comment: Please don't post your answer backwards. It makes your answer very difficult to read. If you're worried about spoilers you can just put part of your answer in spoiler tags by putting >! at the start of your line.